# Change the content of text files at once using python

Tags: python

Hello I have a lot of text files

I want to change their contents to the same phrase. I tried this and it didn't work.

I want to read all the text files open them and change the content to just one same phrase.

```py
import os

text_files = []
os.chdir(os.path.join("data"))
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        text_files.append("data/" + filename)
    with open(filename , "w") as outfile:
        for text in text_files:
            outfile.write("new content")
        outfile.close()
os.chdir("..")
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.  "didnt work"[sic] is not a problem specification.

Comment: `image_files` is an empty list. You won't write anything.

Comment: The immediate problem is that your `write` operations depend on the contents of `image_files`.  Since that list is empty, you write nothing.

Comment: sorry i copied the wrong code can you look now

Answer (score 0):

```
import os

os.chdir("data")
for filename in os.listdir(os.getcwd()):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(filename, "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write("new content")
```

There's no need to use 'data/' in the path as you change into the directory.

You also don't need two for loops, your indentation is also off.

This works.

Answer (score 0):

Please fix your indentation. As far as I have understood this is probably what you are trying to do:

```py
import os

text_files = []

# get all file names that end with .txt
for filename in os.listdir("data"):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        text_files.append(os.path.join("data" , filename))

# open each file and over-write the text "new content" 
for file in text_files:      
    with open(file , "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write("new content")
```

There are a few unnecessary lines of code in your code...

For example:

`os.chdir(os.path.join("data"))`

isn't neessasary as `os.path.join("data")` will simply return `"data"`, so `os.chdir("data")` would have sufficed...

And then again, you can just do `os.listdir("data")` to get the list of files/folders in `"data"` without having to change your directory.

In fact, the code above can be simplified even more:

```py
import os

for filename in os.listdir("data"):
    if filename.endswith(".txt"):
        with open(os.path.join("data" , filename) , "w") as outfile:
            outfile.write("new content")
```